# Internationalization of output in package skak

Tags: xetex, languages

I am using the skak package to print chess games with some success. I would like to ask if it is possible to output the moves, changing the names of the squares to another language. For example, for the greek language I would like to apply the following transformation:

a --> α, b --> β, c--> γ, d--> δ, e--> ε, f--> ζ, g--> η, h--> θ.

If this is not a feature of skak, perhaps there is also another way that latex (or xelatex, which is what I am using) can do the above replacement for some part of a document.

Comment: Could you please make an example of `skak` input to play with?

Comment: This question is a little strange since ["Algebraic notation is the official notation of FIDE which must be used in all recognized international competition involving human players."](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chess_notation). Although letters for the pieces may vary according to language, [Figurine Algebraic Notation along with various annotation symbols](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_notation_(chess)) is the way chess has been internationalized already as popularized by [Chess Informant](http://www.chessinformant.rs/system-of-signs/)

Comment: Okay, but I am not writing scoresheets of tournament games. I am trying to typeset chess moves in the Greek language.

Comment: @egreg example:\usepackage{skak} \begin{document} \newgame
\mainline{1.e4 e5 2. Nf3 Nc6 3.Bb5} \end{document}

Comment: Is it usual for greek chess players to note their moves in this way? Would they really use alpha etc? Do normal chess boards show alpha etc?

Comment: In the past all books were typeset in greek, and even today all newspapers that I know of publish games and problems in greek. But it is true that since 15 years or so, there are also some greek magazines that use latin letters for the files. Verbal communication is always in greek.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's funny, even though [`skak`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/chess/skak) was built with support for various **input** languages, this support only extends to the names of chess **pieces**, not **files** (i.e., column names).

For a start, try the following.  I used `babel` for greek, but it would have been the same with, say, `xelatex`.  (**Change log**: 0. Basic translation; 1. Fixed captures and ambiguous moves.).

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[greek]{babel}
\usepackage{skak}
\makeatletter
\def\TranslateFile#1%
 {\EqStr{#1}{a}{a}
 {\EqStr{#1}{b}{b}
 {\EqStr{#1}{c}{g}
 {\EqStr{#1}{d}{d}
 {\EqStr{#1}{e}{e}
 {\EqStr{#1}{f}{z}
 {\EqStr{#1}{g}{h}
 {\EqStr{#1}{h}{j}{}}}}}}}}}
\def\printmove@san{%
  \EqPiece{Z}{\PieceNameToMove}%
  {\Castling%
    {\LongCastling{\castlingchar\castlinghyphen}{}%
      \castlingchar\castlinghyphen\castlingchar}%
    {%pawn move
      \Capture{\TranslateFile{\FileDiscriminator}\capturesymbol}{}%
      \TranslateFile{\MoveToFile}\MoveToRank%
      \Promotion{\cfss@textsymfigsymbol{\PromotionPieceName}}{}}}%
  {% piece move
    \cfss@textsymfigsymbol{\PieceNameToMove}%
    \EqStr{Z}{\FileDiscriminator}{}{\TranslateFile{\FileDiscriminator}}%
    \EqStr{Z}{\RankDiscriminator}{}{\RankDiscriminator}%
    \Capture{\capturesymbol}{}%
    \TranslateFile{\MoveToFile}\MoveToRank}%
  % for all moves:
  \CheckTest\MateTest\MoveRest}
\shortmoves
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\newgame
\mainline{1.e4 e5 2.Nf3 Nc6 3.Bb5}
\par\newgame
\mainline{1.c4 d5 2.cxd5}
\par\newgame
\mainline{1.d4 Nf6 2.Nf3 e6 3.Nfd2}
\end{document}
```

[image: moves in greek]

It may not be enough for typesetting all possible games that you have in mind, as my chess is a bit rusty and I cannot predict what the issues will be.  Feel free to reply with comments, if something does not work, and I'll try to fix it.  Καλές παρτίδες...  :-)

Comment: Thank you very much. I need one final touch, because in your solution, pawn captures are not fully translated: e.g. if you change the mainline to 1.e4 d5 2.exd5, the second move is typeset as 2.exδ5, instead of 2.εxδ5. (Basically, I think that every time a small letter is encountered in a move, you could change it to a greek letter, because chess notation uses capital letters for pieces -- but I could be wrong)

Comment: ... and now that I think about it again, also ambiguous moves: 1.d4 Nf6 2.Nf3 e6 3.Nbd2

Comment: lol, this is not the first time you are helping me with LaTeX ... I see in your profile that you have also helped me with some issues while typesetting my diploma thesis four years ago.

Comment: I just fixed captures and ambiguous moves.  Cheers...